# Basic operations for linked lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, linked-list

I am trying to write some basic list operations for a linked list in Haskell but I could use a hand with this one. I want to append a list to another but it doesn't work at all, here is my code:

```
data ML a = E | L a (ML a) deriving (Show)

myList = (L 1 (L 2 (L 3 (L 4 E))))

myHead :: ML a -> a
myHead E = error "empty list"
myHead (L a _) = a

myTail :: ML a -> ML a
myTail E = error "empty list"
myTail (L _ a) = a

myAppend :: ML a -> ML a -> ML a
myAppend E a = a
myAppend (x L xs) ys = x L (xs myAppend ys)
```

I also got a question on how to show this list as a String like "1,2,3". I got a function that shows it as a list like this [1,2,3] but not as a String.

```
toString :: ML a -> [a]
toString E = []
toString (L a l) = a:(toString l)
```

Comment: The last line should be `myAppend (L x xs) ys = L x (myAppend xs ys)`. And your toString does convert your list into standard Haskell list, not into a String.

Comment: You can use a function or data constructor as an infix operator, but you need to wrap it in backticks, e.g.: ``x `L` (xs `myAppend` ys)``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the basic problem is on the last line:

```
myAppend :: ML a -> ML a -> ML a
myAppend E a = a
myAppend (x L xs) ys = x L (xs myAppend ys)
```

The constructor is `L` and in Haskell, one usually writes the **constructor before its arguments**, like:

```
myAppend :: ML a -> ML a -> ML a
myAppend E a = a
myAppend (L x xs) ys = L x (myAppend xs ys)
```

Now it should work.

About your second question: `toString ML a -> [a]`. Actually an **`[a]` is a list**, not a `String` (well, a `String` is a list of `Char`s: `type String = [Char]`), and guess what: a list in Haskell is a linked list. So that means that your `toString :: ML a -> [a]` is actually more a `toList`.

If you want to write something as a `String`, it means **the elements should be have a textual representation**. You can write that by using a **type constraint**, like `Show a =>`. So now the signature is: `toString :: Show a => ML a -> [String]`.

We can convert a list of `a`s into a textual representation, by `map`ping all the elements to their textual representation, and `intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]` for instance with a comma, like:

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

toList :: ML a -> [a]
toList E = []
toList (L x xs) = x : toList xs

toString :: Show a => ML a -> String
toString = intercalate "," . map show . toList
```

Or we can "implement the function by ourselves":

```
toString :: Show a => ML a -> String
toString E = ""
toString (L x E) = show x
toString (L x xs) = show x++',' : toString xs
```

Comment: The append function works fine but toString still doesn't work. Isn't there a simple way to convert an Integer list into a String?

Comment: @Vajk: yeah, you have to import the `intercalate` function first

Comment: @Vajk: what is complicated about `import Data.List(intercalate)`?

Comment: @Vajk: there is evidently another way, since `intercalate` is also implemented in Haskell. Will update the answer.

Comment: You do not add two things together with `(x y)`. You do that with `(x + y)`. The `(+)` operator is a function of the `Num` type class. So the signature should be: `myAdd :: Num a => ML a -> ML a -> ML a`.